# How can one constrain a typescript generic to be an indexer?

Tags: generics, typescript

In typescript you can index into an object using only a `string`, `number` or `symbol`.

I want to have a generic that allows the generic parameters to be used as indexes.

```
function foo<T extends number|string>(a: T): void {
    let x: any = {};
    x[a] = 42; // Error: an index expression argument must be of type...
}
```

If I cast to a `number|string`, it compiles:

```
function foo<T extends number|string>(a: T): void {
    let x: any = {};
    let i: number|string = a;
    x[i] = 42; // OK
}
```

So the type checker is smart enough to know that if `T` extends `number|string` then I can assign it to a `number|string` (which I can then can use to index into an object) but for some reason it won't let me index with a `T` directly.

Is there a way to specify in the generic constraint that the type passed can be used as an indexer?

*Note:* I'm using a generic and not `number|string` directly because I want to constrain the generic to accept only values from a specific `enum` or a *string literal union*.

**Edit:** A more compelling example (and closer to what I'm really trying to do), is this:

```
// The following line fails to compile even though Key is number | string
type Dictionary<Key extends number | string, Value> = { [index: Key]: Value }; 

// Had it compiled I would expect the following behaviour
type Answer = "yes" | "no" | "maybe";
let grades = {} as Dictionary<Answer, number>;  

grades["yes"] = 10;
grades["nope"] = 5; // Should be an error "nope" is not assignable to Answer
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ```
> // The following line fails to compile even though Key is number | string
> type Dictionary<Key extends number | string, Value> = { [index: Key]: Value };
> ```

Use `in` keyword:

```
type Dictionary<TKey extends number | string, TValue> = {
  [key in TKey]: TValue
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually going to pass instances of classes that extend string or number then stick with the generic way but cast it.
The problem is that the compiler can't know what is the type of the passed value (at runtime) so it warns you, by casting you're telling it that it's alright and it should trust you.

If you only want to restrict the type of the argument to a specific enum or string literals, then you can do this:

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, C };

function foo(a: MyEnum): void;
function foo(a: "A" | "B" | "C"): void;
function foo(a: any): void {
    let x: any = {};
    x[a] = 42;
}
```

---

#### Edit

Ok, you can use `toString` instead of casting:

```
function foo<T extends number|string>(a: T): void {
    let x: any = {};
    x[a.toString()] = 42;
}
```

But if you're using it then you can pretty much pass anything (as long as it has a `toString` method).
This works great because the keys of objects are always strings in javascript, even when doing:

```
let o = { 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three" };
Object.keys(o).forEach(key => console.log(typeof key)); // string (x3)
```

Otherwise you'll need to cast.

---

#### 2nd Edit

You have two options:

(1) casting:

```
class A<T extends number | string> {
    private x: any;
    private key: T;

    constructor(key: T) {
        this.x = {};
        this.key = key;
    }

    fn(value: any) {
        this.x[this.key as number | string] = value;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%3CT%20extends%20number%20%7C%20string%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20x%3A%20any%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20key%3A%20T%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(value%3A%20T)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.key%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn(value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%5Bthis.key%20as%20number%20%7C%20string%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

(2) toString:

```
class A<T extends number | string> {
    private x: any;
    private key: T;

    constructor(key: T) {
        this.x = {};
        this.key = key;
    }

    fn(value: any) {
        this.x[this.key.toString()] = value;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%3CT%20extends%20number%20%7C%20string%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20x%3A%20any%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20key%3A%20T%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(value%3A%20T)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.key%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn(value%3A%20any)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%5Bthis.key.toString()%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

They are both equivalent as javascript will call `toString` itself before using the variable as the index in an object.

You'd might expect that the compiler will just let you do that, but it just tries to protect you.
As the keys will always be strings, using `toString` then this enforcment by the compiler seems weird to begin with, after all this works in javascript:

```
let obj = {};
let date = new Date();
obj[date] = 3;
```

But will raise a compilation error:

> An index expression argument must be of type 'string', 'number',
>   'symbol', or 'any'

I guess that the reason for this is that as a developer, if it wouldn't error, you'd think that the key is an instance of `Date` and will then expect to get it back when iterating the keys (for example).

By raising an error the compiler let's you know that you're doing something that isn't as straight forward as you might expect, but with casting you tell it that you are aware of that.

---

#### 3rd edit

What you want is currently not possible, but it will be as of typescript 2.1.3.
More in this issue: [String literal types as index signature parameter types?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5683)

But, if this is your scenario then you can simply use the [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
type Answer = "yes" | "no" | "maybe";

let grades = new Map<Answer, number>();
grades.set("yes", 10);
grades.set("nope", 5); // error: Argument of type '"nope"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Answer'
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Answer%20%3D%20%22yes%22%20%7C%20%22no%22%20%7C%20%22maybe%22%3B%0A%0Alet%20grades%20%3D%20new%20Map%3CAnswer%2C%20number%3E()%3B%0Agrades.set(%22yes%22%2C%2010)%3B%0Agrades.set(%22nope%22%2C%205)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Argument%20of%20type%20'%22nope%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'Answer'))

Comment: I'm writing a generic class, I don't know in advance what types it will be used with but I know that I must constrain the types to be usable as indexes.

Comment: I could use `toString` but I was wondering if there's a way to declare the type so that I won't have to fool the type-system.

Comment: What are you going to pass to this function? Only strings (/string literals) or numbers (/enums)?

Comment: It's actually a class not a function (a state machine) and it can be created either with an enum (the member function will accept instances of the enum) or a string literal union (the member function will accept string from the union)

Comment: And this class is generic only to enforce "indexable" types, or do you have other reasons for it?

Comment: Its generic so that I can say _use object A with enum X and object B with enum Y_

Comment: I've edited my question so that what I'm trying to achieve is clearer, you're explaining is how to work around the typesystem, my question is how can I make the typesystem work with me...

Comment: Well, the type system is restricted, at least for now, typescript is being improved fast... Check my revised answer